# Twitter Bootstrap irregular input sizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How would I style the width of an input box using bootstrap when im using the grid system. In version 3 they say wrap a div around your input and use col-lg-3 if you want it 3 cells wide.

But what if i want it somewhere in between 2 and 3 cells wide?

Is there anything in bootstrap for this or do i have to break the grid layout and set the width myself?

Comment: I suggest just set it inside your page.

Comment: If it doesnt fall within the widths of the predefined cells then the add a class to it and set the width manually.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap supports nested grids. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

This way, to create a custom size of say 2.5 cells wide, you could just place a column of size 5 withing another of size 6.